# How can I host a Svelte app in a subdirectory?

Tags: hosting, svelte

How can I host an exported Svelte project in a subdirectory on my domain? Imagine that example.com is my domain, how can I have *src\routes\index.svelte* correspond to *https://example.com/subdir/*?

When I upload the Svelte export to this subdirectory of the web server, it reads from the console that it cannot find *https://example.com/service-worker.js* among other files, which is true, because it's in the */subdir* folder. But where can I set the base URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set it in `src/server.js`: https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Base_URLs

```js
// app/server.js

express() // or Polka, or a similar framework
    .use(
        '/subdir', // <-- add this line
        compression({ threshold: 0 }),
        serve('static'),
        sapper.middleware()
    )
    .listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Remember to use the `--basepath` option if you're using `sapper export`.