# deploy to web subfolder (url prefix)

Tags: svelte, rollupjs

I am starting with rollup.config.js generated by degit svelte template. the `index.html` has includes like `<script defer src='/build/bundle.js'></script>`, but I want to run the project from a subfolder like `https://www.example.com/subfolder/`, can I change the prefix in the build/output files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I host a Svelte app in a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59111833/how-can-i-host-a-svelte-app-in-a-subdirectory)

Comment: @Tibebes.M thanks. My understanding is that this solution assumes sapper, which is not my case at the moment (html client for a AWS rest api), but it may be useful in the future.  So thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

*Warning: This more a hack than an answer.*

I've read about people changing something in rollup or adding arguments to their `npm run build` but it never worked for me.

In your index.html file, change all the imports to relative paths:

From:  `<script defer src='/build/bundle.js'></script>`

To:  `<script defer src='./build/bundle.js'></script>`

As I said, this is the dirty way to do it and I'm aware of it but this is the only way that worked for me.

Comment: Ok, I take it for what it is - a hack. But that's life. Thanks. I will give it a try.